# How to get $this->pdo values in log file for apns?

Tags: php, iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I don't know about PHP scripts. Am a iPhone developer. I want to enable Apple Push Notification for my iPhone app. Am following tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2. Am getting this following error in my push_development.log file while run the push.php file from Terminal,

Terminal command:

```
unknownc42c032e8297:~ creagx$ cd /Users/creagx/Desktop/PushChatServer
unknownc42c032e8297:PushChatServer creagx$ php push/push.php development
```

Error message in push_development.log file:

```
2012-05-14T10:17:14+05:30 Push script started (development mode)
2012-05-14T10:17:14+05:30 Exiting with fatal error: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /Users/gopi/Desktop/PushChatServer/push/push.php:82
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/gopi/Desktop/PushChatServer/push/push.php(82): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'gopipush', 'uH4q9xQGNAuFW...', Array)
#1 /Users/gopi/Desktop/PushChatServer/push/push.php(36): APNS_Push->__construct(Array)
#2 {main}
```

I want to know what are the values passing through this command?

```
// Create a connection to the database.
        $this->pdo = new PDO(
            'mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'], 
            $config['db']['username'], 
            $config['db']['password'],
            array());

        writeToLog('PDO Value: ' . $this->pdo);
```

I tried to print the PDO values in log file using `writeToLog('PDO Value: ' . $this->pdo);`. Can anyone please tell me how to know the pdo values? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

```
// Create a connection to the database.
        $this->pdo = new PDO(
            'mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'], 
            $config['db']['username'], 
            $config['db']['password'],
            array());

        writeToLog('Host: ' . $config['db']['host']);
        writeToLog('DataBase: ' . $config['db']['dbname']);
        writeToLog('Username: ' . $config['db']['username']);
        writeToLog('Password: ' . $config['db']['password']);
```

Again got the same error message in log file. I think the `writeToLog('Host: ' . $config['db']`['host']); line won't compile until the error fix in `$this->pdo` line. Is it correct? Please help me.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well PDO does not expose those values you could do a `writeToLog('Config values: ' . var_export($config, true));` to see what's in the `$config` array. But your problem might have nothing to do with the username/password/dbname, [maybe your `pdo_mysql.default_socket`-path is wrong](http://prattski.com/2010/08/05/magento-install-mysql-error-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDO is a class... you can use var_dump to inspect it's member variables. var_dump outputs directly, so you can catch it with output buffering as follows:

```
ob_start();
var_dump($this->PDO);
writeToLog('PDO state: ' . ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();
```

To be honest, it's probably just as easy to do:

```
writeToLog('Host: ' . $config['db']['host']);
writeToLog('DB: ' . $config['db']['dbname']);
writeToLog('username: ' .  $config['db']['password']);
writeToLog('Password: ' . $config['db']['password']);
```

This is all assuming that `writeToLog` is a working function you've created. If not, just `echo` instead.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Jhong for your answer. I have tried in push.php file. But, nothing recorded in push_development.log except old message. Can you please help me to find the error in php file? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: @Gopinath : you should put the writeToLog lines before the call to $this->PDO

Comment: Thank you Mr.Jhong. I got the host,db,username and password. Those are the correct values passing through but i don't why this error is occur "Exiting with fatal error: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /Users/creagx/Desktop/PushChatServer/push/push.php:87
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/creagx/Desktop/PushChatServer/push/push.php(87): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'creagxpush', 'uH4q9xQGNAuFWq9...', Array)
#1 /Users/creagx/Desktop/PushChatServer/push/push.php(36): APNS_Push->__construct(Array)
#2 {main}". I did anything wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I think @vstm is onto something with his link :-)

Comment: Mr.Jhong it is possible to print 'mysql:host=' line in a log file? I want to record the 'mysql:host=host,db,username,password' in a log. How can i do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The string is just the same as it appears in your code...i.e. `writeToLog('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname']);`